# Why using Integration tests instead of unit tests is a bad idea?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing

Let me start from definition:

**Unit Test** is a software verification and validation method in which a programmer tests if individual units of source code are fit for use

**Integration testing** is the activity of software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group.

Although they serve different purposes very often these terms are mixed up. Developers refer to automated integration tests as unit tests. Also some argue which one is better which seems to me as a wrong question at all.

I would like to ask development community to share their opinions on *why automated integration tests cannot replace classic unit tests*.

Here are my own observations:

1. Integration tests can not be used with TDD approach
2. Integration tests are slow and can not be executed very often
3. In most cases integration tests do not indicate the source of the problem
4. it's more difficult to create test environment with integration tests
5. it's more difficult to ensure high coverage (e.g. simulating special cases, unexpected failures etc)
6. Integration tests can not be used with [Interaction based testing](http://benpryor.com/blog/2007/01/16/state-based-vs-interaction-based-unit-testing/)
7. [Integration tests move moment of discovering defect further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788436/why-using-integration-tests-instead-of-unit-tests-is-a-bad-idea/1788461#1788461) (from [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo))

EDIT: Just to clarify once again: the question is not about whether to use integration or unit testing and not about which one is more useful. Basically I want to collect arguments to the development teams which write ONLY integration tests and consider them as unit tests.
Any test which involve components from different layers is considered as integration test. This is to compare to unit test where isolation is the main goal.

Thank you,
Andrey

Comment: You should split this into separate question and answer instead of answering in your question.  I would also make this community wiki since there is no one right answer -- it's more subjective and discussion oriented.

Comment: On the other hand, if all unit tests work just fine that doesn't mean that the app will work. The assumptions in the code and unit tests may be wrong. That's why I consider integration and unit tests complimentary.

Comment: Given the edit, I think you've asked the wrong question here. What you appear to want is something closer to "what value do [true] unit tests deliver that is not provided by integration tests?". There is also, as extraneon points out, an inverted version of the question.

Comment: Note that this smacks somewhat (though not completely) of a false dichotomy: e.g. we use FIT tests in addition to unit and integration.

Comment: I have written literally thousands of *integration* tests while using TDD, so your first observation is probably based on some misunderstanding. Also, while integration tests *can* be slow, they can also be fast; it depends on several factors.

Comment: "Integration testing is the activity of software testing in which individual software modules are combined and tested as a group." -  How true is this  in today's world where we have a lot of database (external dependency) and framework like Spring Integration test ? Are boundry of Integration test and unit test blurring ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There have been studies<sup>(a)</sup> that show that the cost of fixing a bug becomes higher as you move away from the point where the bug was introduced.

For example, it will generally cost you relatively little to fix a bug in software you haven't even pushed up to source control yet. It's your time and not much of it, I'd warrant (assuming you're any good at your job).

Contrast that with how much it costs to fix when the customer (or all your customers) find that problem. Many level of people get involved and new software has to be built in a hurry and pushed out to the field.

That's the extreme comparison. But even the difference between unit and integration tests can be apparent. Code that fails unit testing mostly affects only the single developer (unless other developers/testers/etc are waiting on it, of course). However, once your code becomes involved in integration testing, a defect can begin holding up *other* people on your team.

We wouldn't dream of replacing our unit tests with integration tests since:

- Our unit tests are automated as well so, other than initial set-up, the cost of running them is small.
- They form the *beginning* of the integration tests. All unit tests are rerun in the integration phase to check that the integration itself hasn't broken anything, and *then* there are the extra tests that have been added by the integration team.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> See, for example, http://slideshare.net/Vamsipothuri/defect-prevention, slide # 5, or search the net for `Defect prevention : Reducing costs and enhancing quality`. Th graph from the chart is duplicated below in case it ever becomes hard to find on the net:

[image]

Comment: Very confused answer, IMO. No explanation of how the "cost of fixing a bug" relates to "using integration tests instead of unit tests". And it seems to consider *integration* test as the integration of code from multiple developers, which is a separate step taken care of by the team's VCS; to me, a new integration test is run before commiting changes to the shared code repository, as well as after performing any necessary merges; and most projects don't have an integration *phase* nor an integration *team*.

Comment: @Rogério, the term 'integration test' is defined very clearly in the question itself: "individual software modules are combined and tested as a group". This is what I've used and it's also the canonical definition as far as I'm concerned. As to the supposed missing application of cost-of-bugfixing, I *thought* I'd made it clear though I'll see if I can rephrase: you should perform unit tests, not *just* integration tests, because it's easier/cheaper/less-effort to fix bugs at the UT stage.

Comment: And, sorry, try as I might, I could not find a way to make that clearer in the answer so, if you have any thoughts on that, I'm open to them. Otherwise all I can suggest is that you reread the question/answer in light of my comment.

Comment: Ok, more specifically, the confusing part is where it says "If your code fails in integration, you start holding up all your team-mates...". Well, how so? A failing integration test is no different from a failing unit test, in this regard: in either case it will *not* hold anybody else. Unless you mean some other kind of integration, which would need more info. About the "cost of fixing a bug", I still don't see a clear explanation of how/why it's cheaper with unit tests. But ok, let's say it *is* cheaper with  unit tests. So what? That in itself is not enough to claim they are worth the cost.

Comment: @Rogério, if your code has been promoted to integration phase, then it *will* hold up that phase if it turns out to be buggy (unless you back it out). As long as a feature remains in your own little area (UT), it can't really affect integration unless it's required for something else. As to whether it's worth doing UT, yes, you should do a cost/benefit analysis, just as with any other decision. However, I've found from experience that the cost is usually minimal given the benefits, especially since (as stated) you can use UT as a basis for integration testing then build on that. YMMV.

Comment: Ok, I think your last comment confirms the problem with this answer: it is talking about a different kind of "integration", which is not the one the question is about. Instead, it's about writing *only* integration tests, versus writing unit tests + integration tests. There is nothing about phases of the software development lifecycle. In my comments, I assumed a modern SDLC where each developer writes implementation and test code (either unit or integration tests) *at the same time*, not in separate phases with commits in between. And I believe this was the same assumption made by the OP.

Comment: @Rogério, if the OP had a different view of unit and integration testing, I assume they wouldn't have accepted my answer. You may want to at least *consider* the possibility that you're the one on a different page, especially when the OP defines things rather explicitly, such as: integration testing is the activity of software testing in which *individual software modules are combined and tested as a group* :-) That is the very definition of the SDLC integration phase.

Comment: @Rogério: If that doesn't convince you, I'm not sure what will, so it's probably best to leave it there (or put your case across one more time if you wish, I won't argue the point any more).

Comment: I agree 100% on the definition of integration tests that the question uses; never mentioned anything against it in my comments. But nowhere in the question it mentions anything about the SDLC, or about an *integration phase*: this only appears in your answer.

Comment: (ignore previous comment, was by mistake) Where did you get the idea that the definition of integration tests used in the question (with which I agree) is "the very definition of the SDLC integration phase"? Because it most definitely is *not so*. Nowhere in the question it mentions anything about the SDLC, or about an *integration phase*: this only appears in your answer. Please provide a reference, if you can (and BTW, I searched, but could not find any of those "studies that show that the cost of fixing a bug becomes higher as you move away from the point where the bug was introduced").

Comment: @Rogério, feel free to provide another definition of integration tests, though I'm not sure you're going to be able to do that without considering actual *integration* of things :-) But again, if you disagree with my definition of integration testing, ask the OP, they're the best one to clarify any disagreement on what they meant. I'm far more likely to believe my definition is what they meant, *simply because they accepted the answer!* As to the study, see http://www.slideshare.net/Vamsipothuri/defect-prevention, slide # 5, or search for `defect prevention reducing costs enhancing quality`.

Comment: I do thank you, though, for forcing me to go find the study, since I can now add that to the answer.

Comment: As I said before, I *do not* disagree with the definition of integration testing used in the question; it is *you* who disagrees, by insisting that integration tests belong to an hypothetical "integration *phase*". Integration tests, normally, are *developer tests* just like unit tests, ie, they are written as part of the same VCS change set.

Comment: Thanks for finding the study. However, note that (as I said in my very first comment) integration tests *are* created/modified *and* executed "in software you haven't even pushed up to source control yet" (to use your own words). The "implementation phase" from the study comprises the implementation of production *as well as* test code (automated developer tests), while the "testing phase" comprises *manual* testing and other forms of QA testing which are not automated *developer* (ie, unit and/or integration) tests.

Comment: @Rogério, I still can't see that you've explained how to have integration tests without any actual integration. However, since my explanations have failed to convince you, I suggest we just agree to disagree. I see no point in going over this endlessly.

Comment: The "integration" in integration tests occurs simply by exercising multiple classes (or "units") in the same test, as opposed to having a separate unit test for each class; that's it. Or, in the words of the OP: "Any test which involve components from different layers is considered as integration test. This is to compare to unit test where isolation is the main goal."

Comment: There are 2 different types of integration testing that you are both talking about:

a) You have published / released a new version of a package, and are pulling that new version into another package to see if they work together (this situation your code _has already been merged_ and problems found will hold up development)
b) Your code has not been merged and you are testing at a high level all the systems together (problems found here will _not_ hold up development).

I think both scenarios are valid.

Answer (score 41):

Integration tests tell you whether it's working.  Unit tests tell you what isn't working.  So long as everything is working, you "don't need" the unit tests - but once something is wrong, it's very nice to have the unit test point you directly to the problem.  As you say, they serve different purposes; it's good to have both.

To directly address your subject: **integration tests** aren't a problem, aren't the problem.  Using them **instead of** unit tests is.

Comment: If you search Google Images for "testing pyramid" it's worth noting that everyone has their own version, and yet there is such striking philosophical consistency across them all.

Comment: If that's the main difference, I'd probably save more time just going with integration tests alone and hunting down the bug when it flags one, instead of additionally building and maintaining unit tests.

Answer (score 26):

I find integration tests markedly superior to unit tests. If I unit test my code, I'm only testing what it does versus my understanding of what it should do. That only catches implementation errors. But often a much bigger problem is errors of understanding. Integration tests catch both.

In addition, there is a dramatic cost difference; if you're making intensive use of unit tests, it's not uncommon for them to outweigh all the rest of your code put together. And they need to be maintained, just like the rest of the code does. Integration tests are vastly cheaper -- and in most cases, you already need them anyway.

There are rare cases where it might be necessary to use unit tests, e.g. for internal error handling paths that can't be triggered if the rest of the system is working correctly, but most of the time, integration tests alone give better results for far lower cost.

Answer (score 10):

- Integration tests are slow.
- Integration tests may break different
  reasons (it is not focused and
  isolated). Therefore you need more
  debugging on failures.
- Combination of
  scenarios are to big for integration
  test when it is not unit tested.

Mostly I do unit tests and 10 times less integration tests (configuration, queries).

Answer (score 10):

In many cases you need both.  Your observations are right on track as far as I'm concerned with respect to using integration tests **as** unit tests, but they don't mean that integration tests are not valuable or needed, just that they serve a different purpose.  One could equally argue that unit tests can't replace integration tests, precisely because they remove the dependencies between objects and they don't exercise the real environment.  Both are correct.

Answer (score 7):

It's all about reducing the iteration time.

With unit tests, you can write a line of code and verify it in a minute or so.  With integration tests, it usually takes significantly longer (and the cost increases as the project grows).

Both are clearly useful, as both will detect issues that the other fails to detect.

OTOH, from a "pure" TDD approach, unit tests aren't *tests*, they're specifications of functionality.  Integration tests, OTOH, really do "test" in the more traditional sense of the word.

Comment: Surely unit tests *are* tests, even though they are specifications of functionality in classic TDD? Because they (additionally, but not coincidentally) verify that the tested code continues to operate in the specified way after any subsequent changes to the code (made later on, and for other reasons).

Answer (score 4):

Integration testing generally happens after unit testing.  I'm not sure what value there is in testing interactions between units that have not themselves been tested.

There's no sense in testing how the gears of a machine turn together if the gears might be broken.

Answer (score 4):

The two types of tests are different. Unit tests, in my opinion are not a alternative to integration tests. Mainly because integration tests are usually context specific. You may well have a scenario where a unit test fails and your integration doesn't and vice versa. If you implement incorrect business logic in a class that utilizes many other components, you would want your integration tests to highlight these, your unit tests  are oblivious to this.I understand that integration testing is quick and easy. I would argue you rely on your unit tests each time you make a change to your code-base and having a list of greens would give you more confidence that you have not broken any expected behavior at the individual class level. Unit tests give you a test against a single class is doing what it was designed to do. Integration tests test that a number of classes working together do what you expect them to do for that particular collaboration instance. That is the whole idea of OO development: individual classes that encapsulate particular logic, which allows for reuse.

Answer (score 3):

I think coverage is the main issue.

A unit test of a specific small component such as a method or at most a class is supposed to test that component in every legal scenario (of course, one abstracts equivalence classes but every major one should be covered). As a result, a change that breaks the established specification should be caught at this point.

In most cases, an integration uses only a subset of the possible scenarios for each subunit, so it is possible for malfunctioning units to still produce a program that initially integrates well.

It is typically difficult to achieve maximal coverage on the integration testing for all the reasons you specified below. Without unit tests, it is more likely that a change to a unit that essentially operates it in a new scenario would not be caught and might be missed in the integration testing. Even if it is not missed, pinpointing the problem may be extremely difficult.

I am not sure that most developers refer to unit tests as integration tests. My impression is that most developers understand the differences, which does not mean they practice either.

Answer (score 3):

A unit test is written to test a method on a class. If that class depends on any kind of external resource or behavior, you should mock them, to ensure you test just your single class. There should be no external resources in a unit test.

An integration test is a higher level of granularity, and as you stated, you should test multiple components to check if they work together as expected. You need both integration tests and unit tests for most projects. But it is important they are kept separate and the difference is understood.

Unit tests, in my opinion, are more difficult for people to grasp. It requires a good knowledge of OO principles (fundamentally based on one class one responsibility). If you are able to test all your classes in isolation, chances are you have a well design solution which is maintainable, flexible and extendable.

- When you check-in, your build server should only run unit tests and
  they should be done in a few seconds, not minutes or hours.
- Integration tests should be ran overnight or manually as needed.

Answer (score 2):

- Unit tests focus on testing an individual component and do not rely on external dependencies.  They are commonly used with mocks or stubs.
- Integration tests involve multiple components and may rely on external dependencies.

I think both are valuable and neither one can replace the other in the job they do.  I do see a lot of integration tests masquerading as unit tests though having dependencies and taking a long time to run.  They should function separately and as part of a continuous integration system.

Integration tests do often find things that unit tests do not though...

Answer (score 2):

Integration tests let you check that whole use cases of your application work.

Unit tests check that low-level logic in your application is correct.

Integration tests are more useful for managers to feel safer about the state of the project (but useful for developers too!).

Unit tests are more useful for developers writing and changing application logic.

And of course, use them both to achieve best results.

Answer (score 2):

(I think) What is referred here by OP as **integration tests** are leaning more to **scenario** level tests.

But where do we draw the line between **unit** -> **integration** -> **scenario**?

What I often see is developers writing a feature and then when unit testing it mocking away every other piece of code this feature uses/consumes and only test their own feature-code because they think someone else tested that so it should be fine. This helps code coverage but can harm the application in general.

In theory the small isolation of **Unit** Test should cover a lot since everything is tested in its own scope. But such tests are **flawed** and do not see the complete picture.

**A good Unit test** should try to mock as least as possible. Mocking API and persistency would be something for example. Even if the application itself does not use IOC (Inversion Of Control) it should be easy to spin up some objects for a test without mocking if every developer working on the project does it as well it gets even easier. **Then the test are useful**. These kind of tests have an integration character to them aren't as easy to write but help you find design flaws of your code. If it is not easy to test then adapt your code to make it easy to test. (TDD)

Pros

1. Fast issue identification
2. Helps even before a PR merge
3. Simple to implement and maintain
4. Providing a lot of data for code quality checking (e.g. coverage etc.)
5. Allows TDD (Test Driven Development)

Cons

1. Misses scenario integration errors
2. Succumbs to developer blindness in their own code(happens to all of us)

**A good integration test** would be executed for complete end to end scenarios and even check persistency and APIs which the unit test could not cover so you might know where to look first when those fail.

Pros:

1. Test close to real world e2e scenario
2. Finds Issues that developers did not think about
3. Very helpful in microservices architectures

Cons:

1. Most of the time slow
2. Need often a rather complex setup
3. Environment (persistency and api) pollution issues (needs cleanup steps)
4. Mostly not feasible to be used on PR's (Pull Requests)

TLDR: You need both you cant replace one with the other! The question is how to design such tests to get the best from both. And not just have them to show good statistics to the management.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to "use integration tests ***instead of*** unit tests" because it means you aren't appreciating that they are testing different things, and of course passing and failing tests will give you different information. They make up sort of a ying and yang of testing as they approach it from either side.

- Integration tests take an approach that simulates how a user would interact with the application. These will cut down on the need for as much manual testing, and passing tests will can tell you that you app is good to go on multiple platforms. A failing test will tell you that something is broken but often doesn't give you a whole lot of information about what's wrong with the underlying code.
- Unit tests should be focusing on making sure the inputs and outputs of your function are what you expect them to be in all cases. Passing units tests can mean that your functions are working according to spec (assuming you have tests for all situations). However, all your functions working properly in isolation doesn't necessarily mean that everything will work perfectly when it's deployed. A failing unit test will give you detailed, specific information about why it's failing which should in theory make it easier to debug.

In the end I believe a combination of both unit and integration tests will yield the quickest a most bug-free software. You could choose to use one and not the other, but I avoid using the phrase "instead of".

Answer (score 1):

How I see integration testing & unit testing:

**Unit Testing:** Test small things in isolation with low level details including but not limited to 'method conditions', checks, loops, defaulting, calculations etc.

**Integration testing:** Test wider scope which involves number of components, which can impact the behaviour of other things when married together. Integration tests should cover end to end integration & behaviours. The purpose of integration tests should be to prove systems/components work fine when integrated together.